# purple screen boot 12.04 (black with recovery mode)

Tags: 12.04, boot, asus

So I have a problem with my asus computer:
everything went just fine until today, 
my computer shows me the grub menu when I start up like it usually does.
But when I choose a version of linux the only thing I get is a  purple screen or a black one if I use the recovery mode.

I have been using ubuntu 12.04 for about a month and I did not download a single update the day before it started to act like this. It was also running perfectly fine on start up until today.

I tried to replace quiet splash with nomodeset but that didn't help,
running an older version of linux didn't help either, as I have the same problem on
every version.

I have an
`Asus motherboard`
`8 Gb DDR3 Ram` 
`Nvidia GTX 560 graphics card`
`Intel i7 quad core processor`

(Someone posted a similar question here: https://askubuntu.com/q/258010 but nobody answered :/)

*Edit*
Boot repair didn't solve the problem, here is the link it gave me:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/6033493/

*Second Edit:* 
ctrl alt delete who worked before the boot repair doesn't work anymore... :/
(I could use it when I had the purple/black screen)

*3th edit:*
The Grub commandline works, so maybe it's a problem with graphics? 
(Even though I didn't change anything when I last used my laptop on Ubuntu..)

Last edit:
Seems like this was marked as a duplicate, the answers provided didn't solve the problem
at all.. As I couldn't find the source of the problem I reinstalled ubuntu... 
(Wich completely crashed my computer, due to a fatal error while trying to install the grub, it couldn't find the device.. But that's not part of the question anymore :).)

But thanks for your fast answers! :)

Comment: Comment above is the best method for determination of your issue. Give that a try and determine if this helps resolve the issue.

Comment: Used boot repair: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6033493/
This didn't solve the problem...
Should I reinstall the Grub?

Comment: Hi @Pixel, it's unfortunate that the question marked as duplicate didn't solve your issue. If you edited your post to mention that (prior to you reinstalling Ubuntu), we could have re-opened the question and continued the investigation; but you've already reinstalled Ubuntu (and have a different issue), so this question is staying closed. You could ask another question for your new issue...but [search](http://askubuntu.com/search) before you post =P. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you change something in the BIOS like EFI(UEFI) or LEGACY ?
For more info click [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI)

Maybe you could try installing GRUB on your sda6 partition using Boot Repair (Look into the advanced options).

Or sometimes I use Grub Customizer to correct some GRUB errors. Click [here](http://www.noobslab.com/2012/11/install-grub-customizer-302-in-ubuntu.html) to install.

Comment: Well I didn't change any settings in the bios..
(At least, I'm not aware of any changes)
I'll try to install GRUB on my sda6 partition :).
About Grub Customizer, does it work on windows 7?

Comment: That didn't work, and Grub Customize seems like an ubuntu program.. :/